# nodejs, pegar valor de um SELECT mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

[image: IMAGEM DE EXEMPLO]

Bom, eu queria saber, como posso pegar esse resultado, e transformar em variavel e poder usar dentro de funções no script, exemplo pegar esse Name warrior e usar como se fosse uma variavel, tipo:

```
con.query(
  'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id = ?', [userLandVariable],
  function(err, rows){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
  }            
);
```

tem como eu fazer `var username = mysql.Name;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa variável `rows` que a callback te dá é uma coleção, tipo array. Então para usares precisas de aceder via index.

Se só tens uma basta:

```
var user = rows[0];
```

e depois aceder às propriedades, como por exemplo `console.log(user.Name);`;

Se estiveres a usar uma versão recente do node podes até usar desestruturação (*destructuring assignment*) do segundo argumento da callback:

```
con.query(
    'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id = ?', 
    [userLandVariable], 
    function (err, [user]){
        console.log(user.Name);
        chamrOutraFuncao(user.Name);
    }
);
```

Comment: entendi, obrigado pela a ajuda ;D